# Is this type of coding thread safe, deadlock safe?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety

Below we have Container of data.  We want multiple threads to be able to search Container and get the Data objects.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::shared_ptr;
using  boost::mutex;
using  boost::lock_guard;
using std::string;

class CData
{
public:
    bool find(string& value, const string& fieldName)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
        auto it=m_data.find(fieldName);
        if( it!=m_data.end())
        {
            value=it->second;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    CData(const CData& rhs)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(rhs.m_lock);
        m_data=rhs.m_data;
    }

    CData& operator=( const CData& rhs ) 
    {
       if ( this == &rhs ) 
       {
           return *this; 
       }

       mutex* lock1;
       mutex* lock2;

       if(this<&rhs)
       {
           lock1=&m_lock;
           lock2=&rhs.m_lock;
       }
       else
       {
           lock1=&rhs.m_lock;
           lock2=&m_lock;
       }

       lock_guard<mutex> guard1(*lock1);
       lock_guard<mutex> guard2(*lock2);

       m_data=rhs.m_data;
    }



private:

    std::map<string,string> m_data;
    mutable mutex m_lock;
};
```

The Container holds shared pts in a map.   Different thread will look up objects in container and lookup the fields in the objects.

```
class CDataContainer
{
public:
    CDataContainer* instance()
    {
        static CDataContainer* s_instance;
        static mutex s_instanceLock;
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(s_instanceLock);
        if(!s_instance)
        {
            s_instance=new CDataContainer;
        }
        return s_instance;
    }

    void insert(const string& key, const shared_ptr<CData>& data)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
        m_key2data[key]=data;
    }


    void erase(const string& key)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
        m_key2data.erase(key);
    }

    bool find(shared_ptr<CData>& data,const string& key)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
        auto it=m_key2data.find(key);
        if( it!=m_key2data.end())
        {
            data=it->second;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



private:
    CDataContainer()

    }

    mutex m_lock;
    std::map<string,shared_ptr<CData>> m_key2data;
};
```

Comment: For starters note that `p0 < p1` is only defined if `p0` and `p1` are part of the same array object. Otherwise the behavior is undefined. You may be able to use `std::less<void const*>()(p0, p1)`, though as this operation is defined even if `p0` and `p1` are not part of the same array.

Comment: Using the address to ensure locking order is creative, but you probably don't want to try to implement your own concurrent version of an STL type.  This is probably a better post for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: OK understood.  I'll have to use a unique id for each CData, which shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, it's probably not that efficient with all those mutexes all over the place though. If I could suggest a small modification:

```
class CData
{
public:
    void insert(const string& key, const shared_ptr<CData>& data) const;
    ...
private:
    const std::map<string,string> m_data;
};
```

Now you don't need any mutexes in `CData` and you can be a lot more assured of its thread safety. Really the way forward with multi-threading is to think of it in terms of constness. I suggest reading [Bartosz's blog](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2013/12/10/functional-data-structures-and-concurrency-in-c/) where he shows how to write threadsafe C++ without mutexes or synchronisation simply through use of immutability.

**Edit:** as an additional note the correct way to acquire multiple mutexes without deadlock is to use [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock), as in:

```
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(m_lock, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(rhs.m_lock, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(lk1, lk2);
```

**Edit2:** also the synchronisation in CDataContainer::instance is unnecessary in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_C.2B.2B11) and it is now perfectly safe to do:

```
CDataContainer& instance()
{
    static CDataContainer s_instance;
    return s_instance;
}
```

Comment: If you look at his class he isn't inserting into it. If it turns out that he does want that functionality it is still possible to update while maintaining immutability and thread safety as the link I referenced demonstrates.

Comment: But you have an `insert` member function.. did you intend to copy the `find` member function of `CData`?

Comment: I forgot to add one member function to CData.  This is a merge member function that will modify the data in CData.    Would I still not need a mutex.  I'll check out your link.

Comment: My whole goal with most of this is to avoid copying CData because currently I have a structure where CData is copied and that is bottleneck that I have found.

Comment: The most practical advice I can give you now then is to use something like http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm instead of trying to roll your own solution. It's hard to give a good answer without knowing lots of specifics but if merges only happen occasionally and copying isn't that prohibitive you may be able to get away with a simple copy and swap implementation while keeping your data const.

Answer (score 0):

This question probably belongs on codereview (at least that's what I've heard).

For `CData::operator=()` you can probably avoid issues about lock ordering or comparing addresses by doing something like:

```
CData& operator=( CData tmp ) 
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock); 
    m_data=std::move(tmp.m_data);
}
```

I think it's simpler, clearer and I doubt there's any significant performance hit. Except for the oddball self-assignment case where it'll still work correctly, but will take a couple locks and copy `m_data` needlessly.

You might want to also define move copy and assignment members.